# Delphi XE "Place debug information in separate TDS file" and "Debug Information"

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Delphi XE's project linking option has a new option:

```
Place debug information in separate TDS file
```

Is there any different with the following combination when compile a project:

1. Checked "Debug Information" and Checked "Place debug information in separate TDS file"
2. Unchecked "Debug Information" and Checked "Place debug information in separate TDS file"

I feel that once "Place debug information in separate TDS file" was checked, checked or unchecked "Debug Information" option doesn't play any role in the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the "Debug Information" option is only to add debugging information inside the EXE, i.e. create debugging information for some external debuggers or profilers, which are able to extract those from the exe. There are several formats arounds, but most rely [on the PE chunked format](http://www.debuginfo.com/articles/debuginfomatch.html#debuginfoinpe).

This option has nothing to do with "Place debug information in separate TDS file".

You can select either one, either both, either none.

*Edited: more accurate answer*

Comment: That is my interpretation as well. Of course, that could easily be checked: check both checkboxes, build, remove the .tds file and check if you can still debug with debug info. That should be in the .dcu.

Comment: I deleted my answer because the setting in question appears to be a linker option in addition to the compiler debug setting.

Comment: There are 2 "Debug Information" in Project Options.  One in "Compiling" tab and another in "Linking" tab.  I am referring to Linking tab's "Debug Information".  Anyway, I also don't know what is the different for both "Debug Information".

Answer (score 0):

Anecdotally, it also has an effect on remote debugging. See my findings in the comments to [this blog post on XE remote debugging (which still doesnt work very well).](http://blog.runbits.com/post/Remote-debugging-Delphi.aspx)